# Nginx multiple Subdomain

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have my example domain:
**site.com.br**

And in it present HTML content
However, I want to take a subdomain and show the same HTML content
Example:
**demo1.site.com.br
demo2.site.com.br**

My domain works great, but subdomains don't work

Thanks!

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name site.com.br;
  return 301 https://www.site.com.br$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.site\.com\.br$ site.com.br;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  index index.html;

  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}
```

I've tried every way so that in addition to the domain, the subdomains show the HTML content of site.com.br